# Javascript to display image center screen on event

Tags: javascript, image

I'm writing a script that will wait for someone to put in a code (up up down down left right left right b a) then play a sound and display a gif centered on the screen, then be removed when the gif is done playing.

My problem is that I don't know how to display the gif without document.body.appendChild() which places it at the bottom left of the site. Also, I don't know how to make it go away when done.

```js
if (window.addEventListener) {
  var keys = [],
    sequence = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65";
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keys.push(e.keyCode);

    if (keys.toString().indexOf(sequence) >= 0) {
      // do something such as:

            var iga = document.createElement("img");
            iga.src = "http://s18603.storage.proboards.com/6408603/i/nhMCfCO61NjYc1vLZrdY.gif";
            document.body.appendChild(iga);
            

      var audio = new Audio('http://www.myinstants.com/media/sounds/igathrow.mp3');
      audio.play();


      keys = [];
    };
  }, true);
};
```

Comment: we can't help without better understanding of page structure and css being used. Layout issues need to start with html/css not javascript

Comment: Post HTML code of the document you're adding the image to. If the code is long, use pastebin.com or simmilar site.

Comment: This is part of a plugin that will run on all pages of a forum. Each page has it's own divs within a global wrapper. Sorry if this doesn't help much. I'm very new to this. The test site is http://alchemicaltest.freeforums.net/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible solutions, but without seeing your page code (and assuming you're trying to do everything in vanilla javascript) the only solution that's universal would be to use javascript to set the image's position property to absolute, and then position the image by retrieving the screen dimensions.

```
 var winW = 630, winH = 460;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
 winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
    document.documentElement &&
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
 winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 winW = window.innerWidth;
 winH = window.innerHeight;
}

console.log('Window center X = '+(winW/2));
console.log('Window center Y = '+(winH/2));
```